# Big O Algorithm Analysis

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have to analyze the Big O complexity for the below code fragments:

a)

```
// loop 1
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  // loop 2
  for(int j = i; j < n; j++)
    sum++;
```

b)

```
// loop 1
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  // loop 2
  for(int j = i + 1; j > i; j--)
    // loop 3
    for(int k = n; k > j; k--)
      sum++;
```

I'm not sure how to do so any help provided will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Frank: please read the homework tag wiki

Answer (score 3):

To analize Big-Oh complexity you have to try to count how many basic operations are made by your code.

In your first loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = i; j < n; j++)
        sum++;
```

How many times is `sum++` called?
The first loop happens `n` times, and in each one of these, the second loop happens around `n` times. 
This gives you around `n` * `n` operations, which is equivalent to a complexity of `O(n^2)`.

I'll let you work out the second one.

Comment: The harder one is the second one :P

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I agree that the first loop happens n times, but I think that the second loop only happens n times when i=0. when i=1, it happens N-1 times.

Comment: @user1097856 You're right, and that would give you exactly how many operations? n + (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) ...

Comment: @user1097856 it will give you n*(n+1)/2 iterations exactly. But this is equivalent O(n^2) when we are speaking in Big O terms

Comment: Why did someone downvote? I know what it's like not to understand Big-Oh, i'm just helping out.

Comment: @alestanis Just delete your answer as 'useless' :)

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but perhaps the downvoter didn't like the analyzing of the 2nd loop: "the second loop happens around n times" is not clear, to be exact - it happens on average n/2 times, sometimes close to n, and some times close to 1. The definition of big O is missing as well. Nevertheless - it is not a reason for downvoting IMHO, especially without commenting with the reason :|.

Comment: @amit i'm still confused. how to see that the second loop happens ard n/2 times?

Comment: @user1097856 because when you sum n + (n-1) + (n-2)... (the operations in each call of the loop) and you divide it by n (the number of times the loop is called) you get n/2.

Comment: @user1097856: It happens a varying number of times, the AVERAGE is n/2. However - I dislike the method of calculating the exact number of operations, and prefer the upper bound method (which is explained in my answer). I find it both easier to understand and use.

Comment: @alestanis i see...i have an idea of how it goes now. thanks.

Comment: @amit okay. i will try to understand the method you have used. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first is straight forward (using the tools of the 2nd code snap, which is a bit trickier) - I'll focus on the 2nd code snap.

Big O notation is giving *asymptotic upper bound* to the number of ops the algorithm do.

Let's assume each inner iteration do 1 op, and let's neglect the counters and overhead of looping.

Denote `T(n)` total number of ops done in the program.

It is clear that the program has NO MORE ops then:

```
 // loop 1
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   // loop 2
   for(int j = i+1; j > i; j--) //note a single op in here, see (1) for details
      // loop 3
      for(int k = n; k > 0; k--) //we change k > j to j > 0 - for details see (2)
         sum++;
```

(1) Since `j` is initialized as `i+1`, and is decreased each iteration, after the first iteration of loop2, you will get `j == i`, and the condition will yield false - thus - a single iteration is done

(2) The original loop iterates NO MORE then `n` times (since `j >= 0`) - thus the "new program" is "not better" then the old one (in terms of upper bounds).

**Complexity of the simplified program**

The total complexity of the above program is `O(n^2)`, since loop1 and loop3 repeat `n` times each, and loop2 repeats exactly once. 

If we assume single command is done each inner loop - the total number of commands which are done is then `n^2`.

**Conclusion:**

Since the new program is doing `n^2` "ops" (according to the assumptions) and the original is "not worse then the new" - it is doing `T(n) <= n^2` steps.

From [definition of big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) (with c=1, and for every N) - you can conclude the program is `O(n^2)`

Comment: @ShashankKadne: thank you, and yeap it is, but I don't see a reason to find what it *exactly* is - the whole point of using `big O` is to avoid calculating the "exactly". Reducing the problem to the easier variation will get you your answer much easier, and we can still prove it is the correct answer - even without knowing the "exactly". This is the main point of the answer actually - no need to know how much iterations are done "exactly" - it is enough to give an upper bound to find the big O notation.

Comment: @amit Sure, as long as it is a tight bound and you don't end up with `O(n^3)` instead when it's `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @phant0m: (1) The question does not ask for tight bount :) (2) I find it easier to find both O and Omega this way then finding the exact number of iterations in many cases (though not always), but it might be a matter of preferences which is different for each.

Comment: I meant a "tight upper bound", not a tight bound as in Omega ;) I'm not sure what the correct term for it is, which is why I followed it with an example.

Comment: @phant0m: A "tight upper bound" is the same as "tight bound", and is `Theta` - to be exact.

Comment: I did mean to write Theta -.- But you know what I mean.